# Jenkins on Jetty - Unable to update plugins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am after some pointers to the problem I have.

I am installing Jenkin 1.450 on CentOS 5.5. Java has been installed and JAVA_HOME had been set properly.
I deployed Jenkins on Jetty 8.0.4. I downloaded Jetty and extracted onto a user's directory. Jenkins is deployed to Jetty's webapps directory.

Then I created a directory outside Jetty's directory, and set JENKINS_HOME to that directory. Then I also set JETTY_HOME to the extracted jetty directory. Then I run Jetty using jetty.sh script which you can find in /bin.

All worked well and I can add users etc. Then from "Manage Plugins" section I see that there is a newer svn plugins, so I want to update it. So I begin the update process. At the end Jenkins tells me "subversion plugin is already installed. Jenkins needs to be restarted for the update to take effect" - so I restarted Jetty. However, checking the version of svn now it was still the same as before and it tells me again there is a new version.

Can somebody tells me where I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set up is good. The issue is with Jenkins itself, and a bug has been opened for this on their JIRA:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12514

While this issue was resolved for new plugins in version 1.450, it remains in the upgrade feature.

Related bugs:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12632
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12583

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue today =)

I tried setting various things in the context:

```
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty"> <Arg>HUDSON_HOME</Arg> <Arg>/opt/jenkins</Arg> </Call>
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty"> <Arg>JENKINS_HOME</Arg> <Arg>/opt/jenkins</Arg> </Call>
```

However in the end the only thing that worked was to crack open the WAR and add the following to WEB-INF/web.xml (where /opt/jenkins is my jenkins home)

```
  <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>HUDSON_HOME</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>/opt/jenkins</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
```

As soon as I did this all the previous installed/upgraded plugins that were marked as missing we present.